# Разная нагрузка на сервер БД в результате разных SQL-запросов

Tags: mysql, sql

**Доброго времени суток!**

Вот мне стало интересно узнать, будет ли нагрузка на веб-сервер большей при  SQL-запросе с такой фильтрацией данных, к примеру:

```
1)  SELECT * FROM table

2)  SELECT * FROM table WHERE Field1 LIKE "%a%" AND ID>5
```

Будет ли нагрузка на веб-сервер при втором SQL-запросе меньшей чем при первом, если, скажем, в таблице over10000 записей?

Answer (score 2):

Смотря где в вашем сервере "узкое место". :)

Если у вас есть, к примеру, индекс по ID, серверу не надо будет перелопачивать всё таблицу. То есть второй запрос будет быстрее (если, конечно, условие отсеивает много записей). Если же индекса нету, серверу придётся по-любому просмотреть всю таблицу, но теперь ещё и вычисляя условие на каждой строке. То есть нагрузка соответственно больше.

В общем, индексы рулят.

Обратите внимание, что (вне зависимости от индекса) объём выводимых данных во первом случае может быть существенно больше. Что соответственно увеличивает время на сериализацию данных (для реально больших баз данных это нельзя игнорировать).

Comment: Да, PRIMARY KEY установлен "стандартом" на ID, как это и положено. Спасибо.

Comment: @Asen: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @VladD, почему это во втором случае объем **выводимых** данных может быть **больше**?

IMHO может быть только меньше (часть отсеится по where).

--

Кстати, для больших таблиц (больше кэша) использование индекса может **замедлить** (иногда значительно) запрос. Дело тут в достаточно большой разнице в скорости последовательного и random чтения с диска. Это происходит если при просмотре индекса будет выбрано больше 10-20% записей (конечно, зависит от запроса, физического размещения блоков данных на диске и главным образом оптимизатора конкретной СУБД).

Comment: @avp: ой, и правда, там имелась в виду первая таблица. Исправил.

Comment: @avp: хорошо бы кроме индекса отсортировать данные по первичному ключу, конечно.

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте что такое планы запросов. Как их просматривать и как их читать.
Посмотрев на план и поняв его вам станет все ясно.

Comment: Возможно, это так. Спасибо.